# How to Add New MPV Speed Shortcuts on Already Existing Shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, mpv

Out of the box, MPV's shortcuts for speeding are <kbd>[</kbd>/<kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>{</kbd>/<kbd>}</kbd>, however, in order to be more consistent with the rest of software I have here, I would like for <kbd>[</kbd>/<kbd>]</kbd> to also be assigned to <kbd>s</kbd>/<kbd>d</kbd>.

How could I do that within `mpv.conf`?

I've tried this:

```
d multiply speed 1/1.1
s multiply speed 1.1
```

But nothing happened. In my specific case, there's also the problem that <kbd>s</kbd>/<kbd>d</kbd> are already being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@mpv-player](https://twitter.com/mpv_player) on Twitter [answered me](https://twitter.com/mpv_player/status/1533266812879642624?s=20&t=0H5yOF0dgoDaJI-EGxKkug): simply do the same thing, but inside the `input.conf` file, which is the proper one for key bindings.