# How do I configure MPV's speed to add instead of multiply?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mpv

I find that multiplying not only has a strange compounding feeling (because it does, obviously), but it also grows too fast. I would much rather have something linear, which calls for an add or subtract function. How do I do that for MPV?

Comment: mpv <=> https://mpv.io/

Answer (score 0):

MPV does have an `add` function for its configuration files. In the case of a shortcut, the correct file to do that is `input.conf`. So, in the end, your configuration file might look something like this:

```
d add speed -.1
s add speed .1
```

References:

- [How to Add New MPV Speed Shortcuts on Already Existing Shortcuts](https://superuser.com/a/1725054/1066947)
- [How to customize the settings in mpv](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/07/27/how-to-customize-the-settings-in-mpv/)